# Cygwin X doesn't work with DISPLAY localhost:0 on windows 10

Tags: windows, cygwin, display

I had Cygwin X 64 bit running fine on Windows 7. I upgraded to Windows 10 and things stopped working.
So I wiped out the Cygwin and installed again from scratch. I installed Cygwin X 1.18.4 (x86_64). I started X server using `startxwin`. I could only get xterm to work when I set `DISPLAY=:0`.
If I set `DISPLAY=localhost:0` I get `can't open display`.

Also I can't have another computer throw a xterm back to Cygwin X. I get same error. I even tried throwing xterm to a Linux host and that gave same error. Windows firewall is turned off and I set `xhost +` on all hosts.

Any advice on why I can't explicitly set the `DISPLAY` to localhost or the local IP of my computer?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned on
https://sourceware.org/ml/cygwin-announce/2015-10/msg00111.html

'-nolisten tcp' is now the default, so the server only accepts local connections on a unix domain socket. A '-listen' option has been added which can be used to restore the previous behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

This is how you can void "-nolisten tcp" option and run [xserver automatiaclly](http://www.trueblade.com/knowledge/automatically-starting-a-cygwin-x-server):

```
    <path-to-cygwin>\bin\run.exe -p /usr/X11R6/bin XWin -listen tcp -multiwindow -clipboard -silent-dup-error
```

Comment: I've never seen the UNIX run command, so I looked it up.  It's explained here https://stackoverflow.com/a/4218609/3281336.  It is a Cygwin only command that allows you to run a DOS program and hides the DOS command window.  It's useful when you want to launch a UI program from a DOS batch file and don't want/need the DOS command shell window appearing.

Comment: Link `xserver automatically` no longer works (April 2021)

Answer (score 2):

I see it's better to use `ssh -Y host` option https://x.cygwin.com/docs/faq/cygwin-x-faq.html#q-ssh-no-x11forwarding

Answer (score 2):

My DISPLAY is set as ":0.0" and it works well.
I got this setting by trial and error but the CYGWIN/X FAQ do say this：

```
    3.13. I upgraded and now X clients can't connect

    A1:

    Since X server 1.17, by default the server does not listen for TCP/IP
    connections, only accepting local connections on a unix domain socket.

    For local clients, use DISPLAY=:0.0, rather than DISPLAY=localhost:0.0,        
    DISPLAY=127.0.0.1:0.0, DISPLAY=::1:0.0, etc. See Q: 1.6.. 
    A2:

    For remote clients, rather than connecting over TCP/IP by explicitly
    setting DISPLAY and allowing access using xhost or by disabling access
    control, use ssh tunnelling with ssh -Y instead. (See the User's Guide
    section on X forwarding using ssh for more details).

    A3:

    Use the -listen tcp option to restore the previous behaviour, allowing 
    the X server to open a TCP/IP socket as well e.g. startxwin -- -listen
    tcp. See Q: 4.2..
```

[CYGWIN/X FAQ URL https://x.cygwin.com/docs/faq/cygwin-x-faq.html](https://x.cygwin.com/docs/faq/cygwin-x-faq.html)